# How to optimize zinc oxide bulk structure at certain pressure with LAMMPS

Tags: molecular-modeling, molecular-dynamics, interatomic-potentials, lammps

I am trying to simulate the Zinc oxide bulk structure (periodic) at constant pressure(0.0 ~ 20.0 GPa) to observe phase transition with LAMMPS.

However, I approached a problem that the ***fluctuating pressure*** in each step of optimisation and importantly the final step of the optimisation ***does not have the value of pressure that I set***.

***5th-edit: the problem is solved ***

**The last step of the pressure is not the exact the pressure that I set for which presumably a form of showing residual force of minimisation. Basically, it went down to the basin but not exactly the lowest point of the basin with a certain tolerance.**

**Primarily the calculation went wrong because I have used wrongly formatted structure data in the read_data command. The wrong data file was produced by three different software... which was very unlucky...**

***I sincerely apologise for the question as I made many people confused.***

Here is my input:

```
units       metal
atom_style  charge
dimension   3
boundary    p p p

#box tilt large                          # allow lammps to have large tilt facotr (xy yz xz)
read_data       data.3_iso0.0
#replicate       3 3 3

pair_style  comb3 polar_off
pair_coeff  * * ./lammps_ip Zn O

neighbor        2.0 bin
neigh_modify every 1 delay 0 check yes

set type 1    charge  2.0  # Zn
set type 2    charge -2.0  # O

##############################################################
#                   type of output data                      #
##############################################################

fix             1 all qeq/comb 2 0.00003 file fq.out
fix             2 all box/relax iso 0.0                 # Pressure = unit [bars], 1 GPa = 10,000 bars, Constant pressure


thermo          1
thermo_style    custom step press temp enthalpy etotal pe ke evdwl ecoul cella cellb cellc cellalpha cellbeta cellgamma

#min_style cg
minimize 0 0.0 10000 10000
min_modify line quadratic

write_data data.*        #produce file for "read_data" command
print " All done "
```

The corresponding output data is:
`Step    Press       c_1          v_press      Temp    v_etot     v_relax     TotEng     PotEng     KinEng`

```
    1157   -186.71231   -186.71231   -186.71231            0  -2.9709191            0   -2.9709191   -2.9709191            0
    1158    -128.7401    -128.7401    -128.7401            0   -2.9709192            0   -2.9709192   -2.9709192            0
    1159   -124.22057   -124.22057   -124.22057            0   -2.9709192            0   -2.9709192   -2.9709192            0
 Loop time of 464.543 on 1 procs for 1159 steps with 216 atoms

 99.9% CPU use with 1 MPI tasks x 1 OpenMP threads

 Minimization stats:
   Stopping criterion = linesearch alpha is zero
   Energy initial, next-to-last, final =
         -2.25448773082     -2.97091924357     -2.97091924466
   Force two-norm initial, final = 351.736 2.00988
   Force max component initial, final = 342.312 0.805865
   Final line search alpha, max atom move = 4.67711e-07 3.76912e-07
   Iterations, force evaluations = 1159 1175
```

Comment: What would you like to achieve, perfect non-fluctuating pressure? You write yourself that the pressure will fluctuate during an NPT simulations. This is usually acceptable and the fluctuations typically go down when the system is properly equilibrated.

Comment: Nice first question. Welcome to the site and we hope to see more of you!

Comment: @Fabian Thank you for the comment. Yes, I understand that NPT simulation will provides pressure fluctuation, but what I trying to do is just simple global optimisation with constant pressure. Is this considered as NPT simulations?

Comment: @DonggiKang What do you mean by "simple global optimization"? Optimize the lattice constant of a known crystal under pressure, or predict the lowest energy crystal structure for a given pressure?

Comment: @Fabian My apology for the unclear comment. I would like to observe the phase changing as the pressure increases, so optimise the lattice constant of a known crystal under pressure.

Comment: @DonggiKang You can use the minimize command. It will simply adjust the cell dimension to minimize the energy. This is not an MD so there is no pressure fluctuation. Keep in mind that you have to test the parameters of box/relax and the minimizer to get reliable results.

Comment: @Fabian I have tried "fix 2 all box/relax iso 0.00000", "min_style cg", "minimize 0 1.0e-6 10000 10000" only. However, it still gives the pressure fluctuation. Any advice on this?

Comment: @DonggiKang I still don't understand what you need. You are performing an optimization so there is no fluctuation. Are you worried that the pressure varies during the minimization? That has to happen because the minimizer is trying to optimize the structure. Only the value at the last iteration is relevant.

Comment: @CodyAldaz I will take your advice in next posts. Apologies for the inconveniences.

Comment: @Fabian Thank you for your many advices. I ran BCT ZnO structure with 0.0 Bar but the final step's pressure is -104.73 and when I increased pressures the error gets bigger (error = |setting - final p|). is it okay to have big error?

Comment: @DonggiKang with "box/relax iso 0.0" you set the target pressure to 0 bar. Change the 0 to your desired pressure and you are done.

Comment: @Fabian I appreciate all of your advice. I have tried with many different value. However, the pressure value on the last step of minimisation does not have the pressure that I set. I presume it caused from the ***no infinite*** periodic boundary system. However, COMB3 and kspace solver cannot be used together because the COMB3 potential already include the long range term.

Comment: @DonggiKang The stopping criterion is "linesearch alpha is zero" meaning the minimizer cannot proceed, not that it is converged. You should try different minimizers, also check the page on fix box/relax. There are many hints why such a thing could happen and what you can try to overcome the problem.

Comment: @DonggiKang You are not doing the dynamics (NPT) in your code. After performing the dynamics, plot the pressure vs timestep of your system at the desired pressure. See if the P(Timestep) slope is zero. If it is, you have reached the desired pressure of your system.

Comment: @Magic_Number Perhaps you might be able to expand this comment into an answer? There's a 100 point bounty on it so we'd all really like it to get an answer!

Comment: @DonggiKang Your question is now on Twitter. Hopefully it will get an answer soon. Retweet: https://twitter.com/StackMatter/status/1270137941097091072

Comment: In your last edit you have said that you solved the problem. I think instead of putting the answer into the question, you should write an "answer" to your own question.

Answer (score 5):

> However, I am not clear which command have to be used to optimise the structure at a certain pressure to have the constant pressure at the final step.

For this you need to perform a time integration from the Isobaric Isothermal ($NPT$) ensemble. Essentially performing these dynamics, you equilibrate the systems at certain $T$ and $P$. In LAMMPS documentation you can find the necessary commands for $NPT$ simulation. A very generic example is given below.

```
fix 1 all npt temp 300.0 300.0 $(100.0*dt) iso 0.0 0.0 $(1000.0*dt)
run 1000000
```

After equilibration, plot $E(timestep)$. If the slope becomes zero, your system is properly equilibrated at that $T$ and $P$, if you plot the $P(timestep)$ after equilibration, it should always fluctuate around Final $P$ as per your input.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. However, what I want to do is geometry optimisation (H=E + pv) not MD simulation. (minimisation enthalpy)

Comment: Is there any specific reason to run optimization only via LAMMPS "minimize" command? May I ask what is the purpose of your work? "Optimization" doesn't need to adhere to "minimize" command just because "minimize" command is designed to minimize something.

Comment: Sometimes I also run very low-temperature (like 0.1K) NPT MD or NVT MD to optimize the system energy and geometry, or sometimes I use minimize command and very short NPT or NVT or NVE MD to stabilize the system. The choice of procedure usually depends on my goal or target of the simulation.

Comment: Also, if you want to really "optimize" something only with "minimize" command, then you can test other minimize algorithms with different criteria conditions.

Comment: You may know about this, but don't forget to monitor system PE, not only pressure, to judge if your system is optimized or not.

Comment: @exsonic01 I appreciate your comments, and I have upvoted them, but next time please use the "edit" button to edit your first comment if you want to add to it, rather than writing 4 separate comments withing a short period of time. This creates a "wall of text" which can be un-ideal. It's too late now to edit the comments, but for the first 5 minutes you can edit them to add things rather than writing more and more new comments and taking up more space.